# React - Ant Design 4 Form InitialValues / form.setFieldsValue

Tags: asp.net, typescript, antd, react-typescript

I tried it also with the "Form initialValues={system}" but the Input fields are still empty. My object has only string values.
Why cant the setFieldsValue or the initialValues read my object?

```
 const ResetFields = () => {
        form.resetFields();
        form.setFieldsValue({
            'name': 'Test', //working
            'street': system.street,    //not working (type is string)
            houseNumber: system.houseNumber, //not working (type is string)
            postCode: system.postCode,
            city: system.city
        });
    }

   return (
        <div>
            <Form
                {...layout}
                size={"large"}
                form={form}
                validateTrigger="submit"
                onReset={ResetFields}
                onFinish={Submit}
                validateMessages={validateMessages}
            >
                <Form.Item
                    name='name'
                    label="Name"
                    rules={[{ required: true }]}
                >
                    <Input autoComplete="off" />
                </Form.Item>

                //More Form.Item and Buttons Submit and Reset...

            </Form>
       </div>
    );
```

Comment: Please post what you tried and what is the error you receive. Also please post your full code.

Comment: See a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/k8jr1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, try this. maybe that will help.

```
'street': system?.street
```